# Java IntelliJ, find the reference bean setup for Autowired

Tags: java, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ, how do I find the reference Bean setup reference file for Autowired? I don't see the option.

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Are you using Ultimate or Community Edition?

Comment: Ultimate version @Makoto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anything `@Autowired`, they appear in the code gutter which is off to the left of your screen.

[image]

(I don't autowire fields; I autowire constructors instead.)

From there you can click on the bean and it'll take you to the definition.

If something here isn't showing up as `@Autowired`, validate your Spring wiring and ensure that the component you're wiring into is being picked up properly.